# Confusion about precision problems with byte

Tags: java, byte, type-conversion

I don't understand the logic behind the following Java code and why the first line works, whereas the others don't:

```
//works
byte b = 50 * 2;

//throws precision error
byte b = 50;
b = b * 2;

//throws precision error
byte b = 100 * 2;
```

Comment: @StigTore: It's -128 to 127, and 2 won't work because `b * 2` is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

@Jon Skeet Yeah second one also gives exception because java applies implicit upcast to such situations means the output of b*50 is 100 but it is int type so you have to downcast to byte..